# scheme continuations -need explanation

Tags: scheme, continuations

The following example involves jumping into continuation and exiting out. Can somebody explain the flow of the function. I am moving in a circle around continuation, and do not know the entry and exit points of the function.

```
(define (prod-iterator lst)
  (letrec ((return-result empty)
        (resume-visit (lambda (dummy) (process-list lst 1)))
        (process-list
         (lambda (lst p)
           (if (empty? lst)
               (begin
                 (set! resume-visit (lambda (dummy) 0))
                 (return-result p))
               (if (= 0 (first lst))
                   (begin
                     (call/cc ; Want to continue here after delivering result     
                      (lambda (k)
                        (set! resume-visit k)
                        (return-result p)))
                     (process-list (rest lst) 1))
                   (process-list (rest lst) (* p (first lst))))))))
    (lambda ()
      (call/cc
       (lambda (k)
         (set! return-result k)
         (resume-visit 'dummy))))))

(define iter (prod-iterator '(1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 7 0 0 8 9)))
(iter) ; 6                                                                        
(iter) ; 120                                                                      
(iter) ; 7                                                                        
(iter) ; 1                                                                        
(iter) ; 72                                                                       
(iter) ; 0                                                                        
(iter) ; 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure iterates over a list, multiplying non-zero members and returning a result each time a zero is found. `Resume-visit` stores the continuation for processing the rest of the list, and `return-result` has the continuation of the call-site of the iterator. In the beginning, `resume-visit` is defined to process the entire list. Each time a zero is found, a continuation is captured, which when invoked executes `(process-list (rest lst) 1)` for whatever value `lst` had at the time. When the list is exhausted, `resume-visit` is set to a dummy procedure. Moreover, every time the program calls `iter`, it executes the following:

```
(call/cc
   (lambda (k)
     (set! return-result k)
     (resume-visit 'dummy)))
```

That is, it captures the continuation of the caller, invoking it returns a value to the caller. The continuation is stored and the program jumps to process the rest of the list. 
When the procedure calls `resume-visit`, the loop is entered, when `return-result` is called, the loop is exited.

If we want to examine `process-list` in more detail, let's assume the list is non-empty. Tho procedure employs basic recursion, accumulating a result until a zero is found. At that point, `p` is the accumulated value and `lst` is the list containing the zero. When we have a construction like `(begin (call/cc (lambda (k) first)) rest)`, we first execute `first` expressions with `k` bound to a continuation. It is a procedure that when invoked, executes `rest` expressions. In this case, that continuation is stored and another continuation is invoked, which returns the accumulated result `p` to the caller of `iter`. That continuation will be invoked the next time `iter` is called, then the loop continues with the rest of the list. That is the point with the continuations, everything else is basic recursion.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still unclear. Can you explain step by step with a lot more detail.

Comment: This is much better than previous one. I understood it after reading several times. Now, I am trying to implement it. BTW, thank you very much. It helped a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to keep in mind is that, a call to `(call/cc f)` will apply the function `f` passed as argument to `call/cc` to the current continuation. If that continuation is called with some argument `a` inside the function `f`, the execution will go to the corresponding call to `call/cc`, and the argument `a` will be returned as the return value of that `call/cc`.

Your program stores the continuation of "calling `call/cc` in `iter`" in the variable `return-result`, and begins processing the list. It multiplies the first 3 non-zero elements of the list before encountering the first 0. When it sees the 0,  the continuation "processing the list element 0" is stored in `resume-visit`, and the value `p` is returned to the continuation `return-result` by calling `(return-result p)`. This call will make the execution go back to the `call/cc` in `iter`, and that `call/cc` returns the passed value of `p`. So you see the first output 6.

The rest calls to `iter` are similar and will make the execution go back and forth between such two continuations. Manual analysis may be a little brain-twisting, you have to know what the execution context is when a continuation is restored.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same this way:

```
(define (prod-iter lst) (fold * 1 (remove zero? lst)))
```

... even though it could perform better by traversing only once.

For continuations, recall (pun intended) that all call/cc does is wait for "k" to be applied this way:

```
(call/cc (lambda (k) (k 'return-value)))
  => return-value
```

The trick here is that you can let call/cc return its own continuation so that it can be applied elsewhere after call/cc has returned like this:

```
;; returns twice; once to get bound to k, the other to return blah
(let ([k (call/cc (lambda (k) k))]) ;; k gets bound to a continuation
  (k 'blah)) ;; k returns here
  => blah
```

This lets a continuation return more than once by saving it in a variable.  Continuations simply return the value they are applied to.

Closures are functions that carry their environment variables along with them before arguments get bounded to them. They are ordinary lambdas.

Continuation-passing style is a way to pass closures as arguments to be applied later. We say that these closure arguments are continuations. Here's half of the current code from my sudoku generator/solver as an example demonstrating how continuation-passing style can simplify your algorithms:

```
#| the grid is internally represented as a vector of 81 numbers
example: (make-vector 81 0)

this builds a list of indexes |#
(define (cell n) (list (+ (* (car 9) (cadr n))))
(define (row n) (iota 9 (* n 9)))
(define (column n) (iota 9 n 9))
(define (region n)
  (let* ([end (+ (* (floor-quotient n 3) 27)
                 (* (remainder n 3) 3))]
         [i (+ end 21)])
    (do ([i i
          (- i (if (zero? (remainder i 3)) 7 1))]
         [ls '() (cons (vector-ref *grid* i) ls)])
      ((= i end) ls))))

#| f is the continuation

usage examples:
(grid-ref *grid* row 0)
(grid-set! *grid* region 7) |#
(define (grid-ref g f n)
  (map (lambda (i) (vector-ref g i)) (f n)))
(define (grid-set! g f n ls)
  (for-each (lambda (i x) (vector-set! g i x))
    (f n) ls))
```

Comment: Here's a concrete example where continuation-passing style is the best way to pass named closures to be applied in the body: